# Alertmanager: how to send alerts only in weekdays?

Tags: prometheus, sre, prometheus-alertmanager, observability

I tried to add this to my alertmanager.yml in root level, but I got this error:
**yaml: unmarshall errors: field time_intervals not found in type config.plain**

```
time_intervals:
  - times:
    weekdays: ['monday:friday']
```

(I used 0.23 version of Alertmanager)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is the following:

```
time_intervals:
  - name: monday-to-friday
    time_intervals:
      - weekdays: ['monday:friday']
```

You can use this time interval like shown in the following example:

```
route:
  group_by: ...
  ...
  routes:
    - receiver: SOME-RECEIVER
      matchers:
        - SOME-MATCHER
      active_time_intervals:
        - monday-to-friday
    ...
```

Comment: Could you please ellaborate more on this? I'm facing with difficulties to apply this in my configuration. So I have one reciever, not recievers and I don't have matcher. It confuses me a bit.

I have something like:

`global:
 ...
route:
   group_by: ...
   ...
   reciever: 'email'
   ...
recievers:
  - name: 'email'
    ...
time_intervals:
  - name: monday-to-friday
    time_intervals:
      - weekdays: ['monday:friday']
`

Comment: Sorry I could not format my comment with line breaks. :\

Comment: Edit your question to add this information.

Comment: Instead of adding an image in the Google drive in a comment, EDIT your question and add the information there. I just added more info to the answer. There's a "routes:" clause missing in your configuration and you need to add a "matches:" clause to instruct Alertmanager in which situation that receiver will receive the alert.

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira How would you add specific time for those days?

Comment: @Shank, use the "times" clause. See the Prometheus documentation here: https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#time_interval_spec